# Nvidia Tegra efficient gstreamer colorspace conversion

Tags: arm, gstreamer

I am developing an application using the gstreamer framework on a Tegra TX1 SoC.

The provided gstreamer plugin `nv_omx_h264enc` provides hardware accelerated H.264 encoding. However, it consumes it's input in some YUV format.

Now I have to encode from RGB sources. In the examples, `nv_omx_h264enc` is usually feed by a `nvvidconv` plugin that does the needed colorspace conversions. However, it only sources from YUV formats I figured out. It can output RGB then, but that is the wrong conversion direction obviuosly.

So I dropped in a `ffmpegcolorspace` plugin for the conversion and got a working pipeline. However, it's performance on ARM CPUs is not very good and so I have a mayor bottleneck.

What else options do I have for the color conversion? Can the `nvvidconv`'s source be modified to provide RGB input pads? Are there other plugins around that would use the GPU or video hardware of the Tegra X1?

Comment: See: [Wikipedia and YUV conversion](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/YUV#Converting_between_Y.27UV_and_RGB) for the formulae.  The conversion is a **matrix** multiply and you need to invert the matrix.  It is probably online somewhere; but one wonders about programmers who couldn't do such simple math?  So of course the conversion should be simple to modify as  only the constant co-efficents should matter (unless one of them is zero and a programmer took advantage of this).

Comment: I have no problem to do some lines of simple math. But this math needs to be done on the Tegra video acceleration architecture, and I guess there are many many more lines and configuration things needed to get this running. Actually some of the existing filters seems to be closed source and it may even be needed to sign an NDA to get the documentation on the hardware API for programming another filter.

Comment: My point is if you have 'YUV->RGB' conversion, the only difference in 'RGB->YUV' is the multiplication co-efficients which are constants and can be found from matrix inversion (not something a CPU/GPU needs to do).  Unless I misunderstood what you have said.

Comment: Ah ok. However, the existing implementation is closed source, so I cannot change the formula. Also, YUV is usually stored with reduced sampling for U and V component, so some more complex things are going on in covernsion, Y, U and V are stored in different locations with different size, but RGB in an consecutive buffer.